# Как добавить элементу div класс animate, при появлении у элемента section класса active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

При scrollстраниц в них добавляется класс active, как добавить класс animate к каждому классу active?

Comment: Ну хоть структуру бы указали.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно вот так:

```js
var section = document.getElementById('mysect');
var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  var top = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if(scrolled >= top) {
    addClass();
  } else {
    removeClass();
  }
  console.log(section.classList.contains('active'))
}

function addClass() {
  section.classList.add("active");
  changeAnimate();
}
function removeClass() {
  section.classList.remove("active");
  changeAnimate();
}

function changeAnimate() {
  if (section.classList.contains('active') === true) {
    mydiv.classList.add("animate");
  } else {
    mydiv.classList.remove("animate");
  }
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
  display: none;
}

.animate {
  display: block;
}
.element {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<div class="element">123</div>
<section id="mysect" class="mysect">
  <div id="mydiv" class="mydiv">213</div>
</section>
```

P.S. Если минусуете, указывайте причину.

Comment: Минус не мой, но я думаю, что его влепили, потому что в вопросе ничего не было про кнопку и onClick. Вопрос не очень внятный, но больше похоже на то, что проблема с отловом появления класса у элемента. Ну и инлайновые обработчики - это конечно прошлый век.

Comment: @Darth, Ну а как может появиться класс `active` в секции? Кнопка это лишь пример того как оно работает)

Comment: Событие, прилетевшее через вебсокет? Расширение браузера? Скролл страницы? Таймаут? Вариантов море

Comment: При скролл страниц в них  в них меняется active и надо чтобы к элементам что в этой секции добавлявся класс для анимации

Comment: @Bogdan, обновил пример.

Comment: Большое спасибо