# Как для тега h1 с классом title добавить класс animate, анимация которого будет появляться, если будет отображаться класс activ в теге section

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Установлен плагин `OnePageScroll` (Сылка внизу), который  тегу `section` добавляет класс `activ`. Как к тегу `h1` с классом `title` добавить класс `animate`,  анимация которого будет появляться, когда будет отображаться класс `activ` в теге `section`.

```
<div class="main">

    <section class="section">
        <h1 class="title">Hello world</h1>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h1 class="title">Hello world</h1>
    </section>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="onepagescroll.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html

Comment: А теперь тоже самое и по русский....

Comment: Подключен плагин OnePageScroll, он при scroll к <section> добавляет class = "active", надо для <h1 class = "title"> добавить еще класс animate, который будет отображаться тогда когда и класс active

Comment: Bogdan,  а `section-ну`, как  добавляет `class = "active"` ?

Comment: добавляет плагин

Comment: Спрошу по другому...  Я не знаком с этим плагином,  а что и как ты делаешь, что плагин  `section-ну,` добавляет `class = "active"`?

Comment: плагин добавляет active при scroll секциям <section="title">

Comment: можно добавить к <h1 class="title"> класс animate, если section =title active"

Comment: Вы же приняли ответ в точно такой же теме, пару часов назад - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782730/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83-div-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-animate-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%83-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-section-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить элементу div класс animate, при появлении у элемента section класса active?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/782730/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83-div-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81-animate-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-section-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: Действительно, к чему один и тот же вопрос?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var h1 = document.querySelector('h1');
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= 100) {
    h1.classList.add('animate')
  } else {
    h1.classList.remove('animate')
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  position:relative;
}

h1 {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
  background: red;
}

h1.animate {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Hello world</h1>
```